# Query multiple collections Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello im trying to join these collections i want to get all users which has "active" attribute equal to false. I couldn't figure out how to acquire this query. There are my schemas:

User Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const UserSchema = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        active:{
            type:Boolean
        }
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Company Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

        const CompanySchema = new Schema({
            userId: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'users'
            },
            companies: [{
                name: {
                    type:String
                },
                country:{
                    type:String
                }
            }
            ]
        });

        module.exports = Company = mongoose.model('company', CompanySchema);
```

Note: Not all users have companies only the type "client" and i want to get both, "client" and "employe"

Comment: can you give an example of your two collections and how will be the output?

Comment: Looks like you're building a total relational application. You probably needs a relational database instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refactor your Schema to better accommodate the type of data you have available.

For example:

User Schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    active:{
        type:Boolean
    },
    companies: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'company'
    }]        
});
```

And Company Schema:

```
const CompanySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type:String
    },
    country:{
        type:String
    }
});
```

Then to get a list of all users who are active, and automatically populate any company data for those users (Assuming your user model is called UserModel)

```
UserModel.find({ active: false }).populate('companies').exec();
```

If you are unable to edit your data structure for any reason, then you could perform a query similar to:

```
CompanyModel.aggregate([
    { $lookup: { from: 'users', localField: 'userId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'user' } },
    { $match: { '$user.active': false } }
]).exec()
```

This will perform an aggregate lookup on the UserId field and then only match on ones where the active property is set to false.